# Can two ing words be placed together?

Tags: gerunds

He heard a loud thumping coming/come from the direction of the store room .
Which one is grammatically appropriate?

Comment: Coming sounds better because it's a continuous action

Comment: It would probably be better to say **a loud thumping noise**.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong with using *ing*s in a row. It happens rarely because the first one has to be a noun, and it's not that common.

On this sentence as Michael said you can also use *thumping noise*, but that's a matter of phrasing, both sentences are correct.